# Laravel search in 2 models with one Query search in Model1 and check a status of Model2

Tags: php, laravel

I have two Models: Trade and User
a user has a status(bool) = 1 or 0 when i search in the Trade Model i want check has the User in the User Model status = 1 and only show this results
models\User.php:

```
public function Trade()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Trade', 'user_id')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
```

models\Trade.php:

```
   public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
```

In the TradeController.php  function:

```
    public function getSearch()
        {       //League must be selected
            $query = Trade::where('league_id', '=', Input::get('league'))->with('User')->open();
            $query->where(function ($query) {
                //Check if Offer selected add clausel
                if ($orb1 = Input::get('orb1')) {
                    $query->where('orb1_id', '=', $orb1);
                }
                 //Check if I want to Buy Selecet add clausel
                if ($orb2 = Input::get('orb2')) {
                    $query->where('orb2_id', '=', $orb2);

                }
```

Now i have a Checkbox called "online" if this checkbox checked i want to get all Trades   where the User status = 1

```
/******************************************************************************************************
//If Checkbox 'online' check get only results with Online Users (status = 1) in the Users Table
******************************************************************************************************/
            if (Input::get('online')) {
                $query->where('users.status', '=', 1);
            }
        });
```

At the end of the function is check has query some results and put the results to the view:

```
     if ($query->count() > 0) {

            $trades = $query->paginate(40)->appends(array_except(Input::query(), Paginator::getPageName()));

            return View::make('trade.trade_table', compact('trades'));
        } else {   

            return Redirect::to('trades')->with('error', 'No Results found');

        }
    } 
}
```

Here a paste: http://paste.pm/d4b.js

thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a answer dont know if the best but works

```
 public function  getSearch()
    {
        $league_id = Input::get('league');
        $orb1_id = Input::get('orb1');
        $orb2_id = Input::get('orb2');
        $is_online = Input::get('online');

                $query = DB::table('trades');


            $query->join('users', 'trades.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
            $query->where('trades.expires_at', '>', Carbon::now());
            $query->where('trades.league_id', '=', $league_id);

            $query->join('ladders', 'trades.league_id', '=', 'ladders.id');

            $query->select('trades.id',
                'ladders.name',
                'trades.user_id',
                'trades.orb1',
                'trades.orb2',
                'trades.much1',
                'trades.much2',
                'trades.expires_at',
                'trades.report',
                'users.ingame',
                'users.username',
                'users.status');

            if ($orb1_id) {
                $query->where('trades.orb1_id', '=', $orb1_id);

        }
        if ($orb2_id) {
            $query->where('trades.orb2_id', '=', $orb2_id);

        }

        if ($is_online) {
            $query->where('users.status', '=', 1);

        }


        $trades = $query->paginate(4)->appends(array_except(Input::query(), Paginator::getPageName()));
        return View::make('trade.results', compact('trades'));

    }
```